# Java Pause JFrame for Input

Tags: java, swing, input, jframe, wait

I am making a program that has a custom JFrame that comes up when a button is pressed, and gets user input. What I need to do is pause the main frame until the input is given. I need it to be just like JOptionPane.showInputDialog(), because what that function does is pauses the calling thread until input is given. How should I go about this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use modal `JDialog`, see [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question can be best answered by looking through the [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) tutorial and examining the many posts on SO with the or similar answer

Comment: MadProgrammer, I have looked up on JDialog, and I'm going to try to use this. This seems like it will work, so thanks for mentioning it, I'll add a comment when I'm done working with it.

Answer (score 0):

Before your dialog box opens up do

```
frame.setEnabled(false);
```

then renable once your dialog closes